# how to write comparison code between string and return of echo in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

```
<script>
 if (<? echo $temp =="xxxxx" ?>){  //the problem is in the if clause
console.log("yyy");
}
<script>
```

it says that unexpected token of ")" in the console

Comment: think: what would `echo $temp =="xxxxx"` do in PHP

Comment: what you should do is look at what the code looks like *in the browser*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix php and javascript. 
I guess you want to do the comparison on the client side.
Try this code:

```
<script>
    var tmp = "<? echo $temp ?>";
    if (tmp =="xxxxx" ) {
        console.log("yyy");
    }
<script>
```

Comment: I'd be more inclined to wrap the result of echo $temp in `"`

Comment: `Your php script will return 'true' or 'false',` are you sure about that? it would result in `1` if true, and nothing at all if false - that's the issue in the question, clearly it's false, therefore the code in the browser is `if () {`

Comment: so, if $temp is `xxxxx` then the statement reads `var tmp = xxxxx` - still not right

Comment: the php statement will NOT return 0 for false ... it returns NOTHING ... which is why there's a syntax error in the browser

Comment: why not just `if ("<? echo $temp ?>" =="xxxxx" ) {` :p

Comment: You can try, I never test direct string comparison in js.